# React Bootstrap hide tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Is there a way to hide the `OverlayTrigger`/`Tooltip` element by default?
eg. `overlay={this.state.show ? <Tooltip>showing</Tooltip> : null}` works but throws a warning on console:

> The prop `overlay` is marked as required in `OverlayTrigger`, but its value is `null`

Would this be the only way?

```
{!this.state.show ? {component} :
 <OverlayTrigger ...>
   {component}
 </OverlayTrigger>
}
```

Comment: You are closing your curly-braces too early. Try: `overlay={this.state.show ? <Tooltip>showing</Tooltip> : null}`.

Comment: @Chris minor typo. The corrected version still throws "The prop `overlay` is marked as required in `OverlayTrigger`, but its value is `null`"

Comment: @Avery235: try an empty string instead of `null`

Comment: @FiriceNguyen with '' it shows a tooltip with `''`, with nothing at all it shows `Cannot read property 'props' of null
    at OverlayTrigger.render`

Comment: An empty string doesn't work, it still throws an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `OverlayTrigger` component must have a `overlay` prop passed. If you don't want the tooltip, you also don't want an overlay to trigger. Hence, you'd want to remove it if `this.state.show` is falsy.

```
{this.state.show 
  ? <OverlayTrigger overlay={<Tooltip>showing</Tooltip>}>
      <button>Click me!</button>
    </OverlayTrigger>
  : <button>Click me!</button>
}
```

*Edit:* Yes, the code in your update would be the way to do it.

Comment: This doesn't help when instead of a simple button you have some content you want to display, but don't have any tooltip for; you'd have to duplicate more than just a button with some text. It should be possible to have an empty overlay with react-bootstrap simply displaying the content without a tooltip. As a workaround, I had to add a class to hide the tooltip in the overlay when I have nothing to show, which is just plain silly.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! I already have a component to abstract all the ugly 'OverlayTrigger' code into a neat `<Tooltip />` wrapper, so adding this to that was a breeze! I threw a 'disabled' prop onto the <Tooltip />, and used the 'this.props.children' in my abstracted component to replicate the "button" (or whatever else is being wrapped in the tooltip) neatly for the above code!

Comment: thank you, I first tried the solution below this but was getting nasty errors related to properties not have set values. This solution ended up resolving all the problems.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me, shows only when boolean is true.

```
<OverlayTrigger
  overlay={
    boolean ? (
      <Tooltip id={`tooltip`}>important message for user</Tooltip>
    ) : (
      <span></span>
    )
  }
>
{children}
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Comment: I believe this is preferable to the accepted solution. I'm not getting any errors, and this way you don't have to duplicate or make a special component for your button. Rather, you simply make the ToolTip conditionally render. Nice!

Comment: thanks Tom Adam I agree with @JB Wilson, your answer is the better. While still not the "accepted" at least I could vote yours to the top. For editing I found it easier to find/replace "overlay={" to "overlay={!boolean ? <span></span> : ". Normally, I try to reserve negative semantics for the "else", but in this case I had many overlays. I'll go back to refactor after I'm confident there are no ill side-effects